# SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm running a plugin that displays an events calendar. It works great in all browsers except in IE compatibility mode. When that option is checked, the calendar disappears. I believe its a JS error.

IE Debugger Error:

```
element.qtip({
    content: {
    text: event.description,
    title: {
    text: 'Description',
    }
  },
position: {
    at: 'top right',
    adjust: {
    x: 0, y: 30
   },
},
```

In my plugin editor this is the code:

```
element.qtip({
  content: {
  text: event.description,
  title: {
  text: '<?php _e('Description', 'event_espresso'); ?>',
  }
},
position: {
   at: 'top right',
   adjust: {
   x: 0, y: 30
  },
},
```

I'm not great at debugging so any help would be appreciated.

If it helps, here is the page: http://www.mbausa.org/calendar/

Comment: Tip: parenthesis come in pairs.

Comment: adding a side note, this error also occurs when you have "" as an identifier (array key).

Comment: I get the same error in KnockOut with this binding:
attr: {id: Rno, class: 'resultList access' + SecurityLevel(), click: $root.viewDetails}

Can anyone see the error there?

Comment: @thomas class is reserved on IE8. Try 'class' instead.

Answer (score 46):

Internet Explorer have troubles with trailing commas in objects and arrays;

```
title: {
    text: 'Description', //<--
}
```

You probably want:

```
title: {
    text: 'Description'
}
```

Comment: This is unbelievable: both ie8 and ie9 render my gmap3 code without problems but ie7 complain with that error because of the trailing comma. THX you saved my afternoon.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my IE8 compatibility.

Comment: Isn't it in reality because the standards specify that this is invalid code? People should stop complaining in that case, since it's just all the other browsers that don't follow the standards and parse the malformed code.

Answer (score 11):

There are 2 common causes for this error.  Either having a trailing comma when inappropriate, or using a JavaScript reserved word.  In your case, you have 2 unnecessary commas.  Below is the correct code snippet, with comments where I removed the commas.

```
element.qtip({
  content: {
  text: event.description,
  title: {
    text: '<?php _e('Description', 'event_espresso'); ?>' // Removed Comma
  }
},
position: {
  at: 'top right',
  adjust: {
    x: 0, y: 30
  } // Removed Comma
},
```

I actually did a blog post (and video) explaining the error and showing examples and fixes.  It can be found here: http://mikemclin.net/fixing-error-script1028-expected-identifier-string-or-number/

Comment: i had this error with parsleyjs remote 2.x -- IE < 10 would crash because a key used was called *default* and it's a reserved word. i changed to 'default' and it works in case you're wondering. also pushed a fix on github for it.

Comment: The irony here is that most linter rulesets for JS & TS enforce the addition of trailing commas....

Answer (score 8):

Old version of IE doesn't support mal-formated JSON String.

You should never put a comma ',' separator when no braces '[', accolades '{' or new object properties come after.

Try :

```
position: {
at: 'top right',
adjust: {
   x: 0, y: 30
  } // <-- no comma here
},
```

instead of :

```
position: {
at: 'top right',
adjust: {
   x: 0, y: 30
  }, // <-- comma here
},
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I also had to remove the comma after

     text: '<?php _e('Description', 'event_espresso'); ?>',

I can see the calendar now in Compatibility mode but I'm getting a new error:


Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'delegate'

Comment: Thanks! I keep forgetting this... Chalk up one more wasted hour for IE! What? Is MicroSoft getting paid on commission?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Vuex and the issue manifests at the `computed` hook calling `mapState`, then the issue is with the spread operator.

```
},
computed: {
  ...mapState({
```

Use babel to fix it:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread

Answer (score 3):

Rather than work round compatibility mode you can force non-compatibility mode with...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

in your `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible error is due to the reserved keyword being used as hash key.

[IE8 errors when defining a Javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323586/ie8-errors-when-defining-a-javascript-object)

When I use `{class:'icon'}` I would also get this error. Other IE8 keywords would probably do the same too.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to import a ES6 module without transpilation through Babel or similar tools.

This row generated the error:

import myES6module from 'my-npm-ES6-module'

The solution is to make sure your workflow actually transpiles it to browser-compatible JavaScript.