# IE8 errors when defining a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I knew IE8 was a pain, but I have never seen it give me such trouble. All I am trying to do is define a Javascript object and it causes an error, stopping all scripting from working on the page.

The error is "Expected identifier, string or number" and indicates that the issue happens where I define the property "class" below. I have seen countless scripts define objects this way, so why does IE8 vomit on this?

I isolated the offending code to this. Placing this in the head of an HTML page by itself and running it in IE8 will cause the issue I am seeing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var atts = {class: "trigger"};
</script>
```

Comment: IE is horrible for "reserved words" that aren't. try changing class to something else temporarily, e.g. "foo", and see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define using appropriate data type by enclosing in quotes, `"class"`

Answer (score 6):

It is because `class` is a reserved keyword. Try putting quotes around it `'class'`

Comment: I've seen many plugins need classes.  The common method is to name it `klass`.

Comment: `className` is another commonly used one (Backbone)

Answer (score 0):

in addtion to @PickYourPoison answer you can also use this trick:

```
var atts= {};
atts["class"] = "LOL";
```