# IE8 Expected identifier, string or number in ajax Coldfusion

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, internet-explorer-8

I am facing issue in my code. It gives a javascript error in IE8,

```
"SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number"
```

My code,

```
<cfoutput>
<cfif iPro eq "M">
<cfset iIdLock = #DecryptX(iId)#>`

<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    var hook = true;
    if(hook){
        var r="#iIdLock#";
       $.ajax({                     
           type:'POST',
           async:false,
           url:"setlock.cfm",
           data:"s="+r,
           success: function(){},
           error: function(){},
        });
    }
}
</script>

</cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Two suggestions.  You don't need those # # in your <cfset>, see [this article](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/when-to-use-pound-signs.html).  And it's always a good idea to run your JS through a validator like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) which would pick up the issue with the trailing comma that Leigh correctly identified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I had used double quotes within Ajax and that is what caused my issue. I just replaced the double quotes with single quotes and everything is working fine now.

```
var r="#iIdLock#"; -> var r='#iIdLock#

url:"setlock.cfm", -> url:'setlock.cfm',

data:"s="+r, -> data:'s='+r,
```

Answer (score 5):

Always a good idea to do a quick search on the error before posting :) A *very* quick search turned up this SO thread:  [SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675622/script1028-expected-identifier-string-or-number). One of the suggested causes is extra trailing commas. Looks like you have an extra comma after the "error" function:

```
    $.ajax({                     
           ...
           error: function(){},    
    });
```

That seems a likely cause, and at the very least it would cause *some* syntax error.